# Button not redirecting to the correct link?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am having an issue with a button that is bounded to a javascript function with onClick();

My interface can ban pepoles on a game server but for now if i select anyone here : [image] It will always select wartog for some reason.

In my code everything looks to redirect to the correct person.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var link="scripts/playerManager/ban.php?player=IIPoliII&serverpath=server/x1&user=Poli";
function editLinkIIPoliII() {
 var x = prompt("Reason:", "");
 if (x === "" || x === null) {
  alert("You entred no reason please retry to ban this player with a reason");
 } else {
  link+="&reason=" +x;
  window.location=link;
 }
}
</script>
<a onclick="editLinkIIPoliII()" href="#">Ban</a></td>
```

Here you can see the link for IIPoliII it looks alright, also if i use the inspection tool it's clicking on the right place.

I cleared my cache and tried also in internet explorer it's the same everywhere sadly ....

Why is it missunderstanding the link?

Comment: Your url has the `player` parameter always set to `IPoliIT` , you're never changing it during the execution of your code.

Comment: @RafaelDuarte Well here it looks like maybe it's overwrited since at the end my link always go on wartog96. I mean i will always ban wartog and not IIPoliII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rafael Duarte said it's because my var link don't change at all. It's not dynamic so i will always apply the lastest player